# Label text missing when scrolling in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am getting this weird error when scrolling

[image]
[image: Label text missing]

```html
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChatTableNewViewCell

let msgtype=CoreDataManager.read(EntityNames.ChatEntity, attributeName: "is_mobile", index: indexPath.row)

if msgtype == "Y" {
    cell.lblRecivedMsg.hidden=true
    cell.lblSendMsg.text=CoreDataManager.read(EntityNames.ChatEntity, attributeName: "message", index: indexPath.row)
}
else{
    cell.lblSendMsg.hidden=true
    cell.lblRecivedMsg.text=CoreDataManager.read(EntityNames.ChatEntity, attributeName: "message", index: indexPath.row)
}

cell.lblRecivedMsg.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
cell.lblRecivedMsg.layer.borderWidth = 1
cell.lblRecivedMsg.layer.masksToBounds = false
cell.lblRecivedMsg.layer.cornerRadius = 8
cell.lblRecivedMsg.clipsToBounds = true

cell.lblSendMsg.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
cell.lblSendMsg.layer.borderWidth = 1
cell.lblSendMsg.layer.masksToBounds = false
cell.lblSendMsg.layer.cornerRadius = 8
cell.lblSendMsg.clipsToBounds = true

// Configure the cell...
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
println(indexPath.row)
return cell
}
```

This happens in both simulator and in iPad, moreover it doesn't happen always only when we scroll very fast or scroll couple of times. This is really annoying :(. Please help

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code relevant to the setup of a cell?

Comment: Could you explain what's going on (edit your question; ***don't*** post it in the comments) or clarify if you did already? It seems like your issue is that the messages disappear but it's difficult to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code it looks like you are not resetting the cell properly.

When you set the text you should set hidden to false for that text view.

Since cells are being reused, you could get one which has been set to hidden previously. That is why it is missing sometimes.

```
if msgtype == "Y" {
    cell.lblRecivedMsg.hidden=true
    cell.lblSendMsg.hidden=false
    cell.lblSendMsg.text=CoreDataManager.read(EntityNames.ChatEntity, attributeName: "message", index: indexPath.row)
}
else{
    cell.lblSendMsg.hidden=true
    cell.lblRecivedMsg.hidden=false
    cell.lblRecivedMsg.text=CoreDataManager.read(EntityNames.ChatEntity, attributeName: "message", index: indexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: Indeed it was, thanks @Rory McKinnel, Since it was reusing the cells it used the first cell in which lblSend was hidden. Now I gave both visible on starting of the function. Thanks a lot Rory.